# Child divs blocking visibility of parent div background

Tags: css, wordpress, html, background-image

I am trying to tweak a wordpress site but can't seem to get one of my parent div's backgrounds to be visible through the child divs on top. I've got the background image set for *#main*. The image I'm using fades to white at the bottom but, in the rendered page, I can only see about the top 23 pixels or so before the rest is blocked...I think by *#primary*.

The site uses a child theme based on [Responsive](http://cyberchimps.com/forum/free/responsive/) and can currently be viewed [here](http://wp.massosteopathic.org). I would copy/paste code for your convenience but I'm no longer certain what part of the code is responsible for what I'm (not) seeing. So I apologize in advance if this is not enough information to go on  :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks to me like you have a float problem and the `div#main` is collapsing. Try one of the various [clear-float](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html) techniques to prevent that.

For example, try `#main { overflow: hidden }` as a test - that will normally prevent the collapse.

Comment: Bingo! Thank you! I'm pretty raw with CSS so I often miss the obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Classic clear fix issue. Give #main an overflow:hidden or try the [micro clear fix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) if any content is spilling out of the box.

```
#main {
    background: url("http://wp.massosteopathic.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/headerhand-contd.jpg") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    clear: both;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 1.625em 0 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! BotskoNet suggested the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

The `#main div` is only 24px high. This is because all child `divs` are floating.

add a

```
<div class='clear'>
```

with

```
.clear { clear: both}
```

just before the closing tag of your `#main`

Comment: The suggestion of overflow:hidden worked in this case but I'm making a note of this because I'm certain I'll need it in the future. Thanks!